# Reply to prompt(); with Python webscraper

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to scrape a website in Python, but it gives an HTTP 401 error. When accessing the website on my browser, clicking on the link causes a JavaScript prompt box to pop up, in which I must type "YES" to view the website. How could I do this?

For confidentiality reasons I cannot share the link to the website.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in 
http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

Popups aren't very well documented, but this should work:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys('YES')
alert.accept()
```

I think `switch_to.alert` creates an `Alert` object, documented here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert

Comment: You state that popups aren't very well documented but then you link you provided has documentation for each of your lines of code...

Comment: @JeffC that link doesn't explain the first line, which is arguably the most important line. There's no Selenium doc I know of that explains BOTH switching to an alert AND doing something with that alert. You only get one or the other, usually with no mention of where to find the other. Even the Selenium tutorial `https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/`, which has examples for many common scenarios, has an alert-related example that just switches to the alert, but doesn't do anything after that.